# Python ORA-12504 error when using EZConnect syntax

Tags: python, oracle

I'm using the python Oracle driver and Easy Connection syntax, but receiving an error:

```
DatabaseError: ORA-12514: TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor

import cx_Oracle as cx_Oracle

def query_route():
    con = cx_Oracle.connect('user/pwd@10.1.1.24:1521/service')
```

The server is version `11.2.0.4.0`.

Following Christopher Jones's answer below, I tried:

```
con = cx_Oracle("oracle+cx_oracle://user:pwd@(DESCRIPTION = (LOAD_BALANCE=on) (FAILOVER=ON) (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 10.1.1.24)(PORT = 1521)) (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVER = DEDICATED) (SERVICE_NAME = service)))")
```

which failed with the same error

I found a link that [suggested I need the service name](https://laurentschneider.com/wordpress/2011/02/ezconnect-and-hostname-resolution-methods.html), but I'm using the service after the slash.

What am I doing wrong?

Update: as Christoper Jones said, the problem was the service name, and my mistake was assuming I knew how that was determined. I had copied from a jdbc datasource:

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.1.1.24:1521:foo
```

however, in the python code, I needed to use:

```
mgowner/mgowner@10.1.1.24/foo.mycompany.com
```

Comment: in your `tnsnames.ora` file your `service_name` parameter may be long with dots such as `mydb.mycomp.com`, then replace `service` keyword with this long dotted description.

Comment: Barbaros: I believe this is the format that's intended to work without a tnsnames.ora file. Am I wrong about that?

Comment: no i didn't mean this full description, and from your edit, i saw that forget about my comment :) , since your service_name is named just `service`(not like `service.mycompany.com.us`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The hostname and port sections are OK: you're getting through to the Oracle Network listener.  Somehow you need to find the correct service name, perhaps by running `lsnrctl status` on the machine hosting the database, or executing `show parameter service_names` in SQL*Plus (as a privileged user).  If you have PDBS, query one of the PDB views.

If your DB is very old, it may be using a SID, not a service name so you will have to construct the long connection string like `"(DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 10.1.1.24)(PORT = 1521)) (CONNECT_DATA = (SID = whatever) ) )"`

Comment: I've updated to show where I tried your advice, as well as with the version of Oracle. The service I know is right, because I've copied it from the configuration of a java process that can connect.